# What should I do if I want to cover 100% of Star Wars EU but don't want to play the games?

Tags: star-wars, suggested-order

I would be interested in knowing 100% of what happened in *Star Wars* Extended Universe down to C-level of canon (limited to what was published till now, d'oh).

The problem is:

- Based on what I read on Wookieepedia, tons of events/characters/story these days is covered by **computer games**.
- While I'm happy to hunt down and read books, comics, or magazines, I resolutely refuse to play any computer games - *Star Wars* ones being no exception.

What are the possible approaches for me to take so that I can achieve my goal in light of the impasse reached between myself and Lucas-licensed gaming industry?

Should I use Wookieepedia (and if so, what are the best tactics for doing so?)

Are there better solutions than relying on Wookieepedia articles? E.g. are there any websites/books/etc. that cover the full or at least main events/plots/characters of each game the same way novelizations cover the movies?

Comment: Google "Let's Play" + game title?

Comment: @Keen- this? http://lparchive.org/history  If so, it seems to be suboptimal - merely videos of game play. Not very good as a source of plot details.

Comment: Perhaps you can search for only the cutscenes (if there are any) instead of gameplay. I'm guessing that any relevant plot detail would appear in a game cutscene.

Comment: @Omega - Could be - I'm not an expert. I'm more used to Final Fantasy, where plenty of plot details are revealed in dialog etc...

Comment: Get the <Star Wars Game> Strategy Guide books, or read the walkthroughs on the web e.g. http://uk.ign.com/wikis/star-wars-the-force-unleashed/Walkthrough

Comment: @PhilPursglove - if you can expand that (e.g. show how a specific game's walkthrough matches or exceeds Wookiepedia in level of detail), that'd be a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

The *Knights of the Old Republic* Series (*KOTOR* and *KOTOR II: Sith Lords*).  Wookieepedia is a great source, however, you will find that the synopsis is based on the **accepted timeline of events** for each game.  If you want to see how the stories would unfold with different characters/different choices, I would look into watching a "Let's play" for the series or reading a walk-through with the different paths a character can take.

For the Old Republic series, I would recommend [**Star Wars: The Old Republic: Encyclopedia**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0756698391) which offers an expansive view of each story told throughout the massive MMO game, and background on the entire conflict.  Great all-in-one resource.

Wookieepedia offers a great synopsis on the *Shadows of the Empire*.  It should be noted that there is a [novel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0553574132) and [comic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1569711836) based on the game.  The [sequel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/156971441X) comic is also available.

For *Rogue Squadron* go with Wookieepedia, it has links giving detail descriptions of each level.  The sequel *Rogue Leader* does not have a detailed description on Wookieepedia, so a guide might be best

For the *Jedi Knight* series (*Dark Forces*, *Dark Forces II*, *Mysteries of the Sith*, *Jedi Knight II: Jedi Outcast*,  *Jedi Academy*), I've found that Wookieepedia offers a very in-depth view of the story arc in each game.  *Mysteries of the Sith* and *Jedi Academy* are lacking in content, however, so I would recommend reading/watching a walk-through of the games.

The *Battlefront* series is covered well by Wookieepedia, with the exception of *Elite Squadron*, so a walk-through/let's play might better suited.  *Mobile Squadrons* was a simple cell phone game, that I would not waste time on.

*The Force Unleashed* Wookieepedia covers.  However, there are novelizations of the [first](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/034550285X) and [second](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0345511549) game by author Sean Williams.  Once again these are based on the **accepted timeline of events** so head over to Wookieepedia if you want to read about alternate endings.

Final Note:  If you're looking for a guide and do not want to spend the cash on an official guide, [GameFAQs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/) offers a great alternative with user submitted guides.  General rule of thumb I would use, would be to check Wookieepedia and if it doesn't have the detailed plot information you're looking for, check for a guide.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above answer, several of the video games are captured in other mediums:

**Dark Forces/Jedi Knight**

This series has it's own set of novellas covering the story:  **Imperial Soldier**, **Rebel Agent**, and **Jedi Knight**. Following this, this character made more appearances in the larger EU (primarily in the New Jedi Order series of books). These cover enough of the events of the associated games that you won't miss anything. There is also an audio drama of these events, though I have not heard it so I can't speak to it's quality.

**Tales of The Jedi Comics/Audio Drama**

The *Knights of the Old Republic* I & II, and *The Old Republic* video games are rarely referenced elsewhere in the expanded universe. Primarily the references to this time period (such as Exar Kun) come from the **Tales of the Jedi** and **Knights of the Old Republic** comic series. These events prequel both games and are covered very well in comic form but also in a fully voice acted Audio Drama.

Note that this is the original trade paperback called *"Knights of the Old Republic"* and not the *Knights of the Old Republic* Dark Horse series released sometime later. That series also has very little to do with the story of the games, aside from a similar setting, similar locations, and occasionally cross-over characters.

**X-Wing & TIE Fighter**

Most of the events of these games are irrelevant to the larger universe, with a few exceptions (like the Redemption Scenario, and later Farlanders appearance in the New Jedi Order book series). However, both games have expanded story in the form of their original manuals. *X-Wing* has **"The Farlander Papers"** which is a small novella detailing his origin and back story, and *TIE Fighter* had **"The Stele Chronicles"** which detailed Maarek Stele and his pursuit to become a TIE Fighter Pilot.

Both of these stories were later expanded in their **Official Strategy Guides**, which detail every mission in a first person narrative and also post mission conversations with other characters and some pre-mission setting building too that does a wonderful job of putting the missions in context.

*X-Wing vs. TIE Fighter* had no real canon story at the time of it's launch, it was mostly just a multiplayer game. The expansion, *Balance of Power*, added in a story-based campaign, but there was, as far as I know, nothing detailing the story, and it was woefully devoid of characters or plot, unlike the X-Wing and especially the TIE Fighter games.

*X-Wing Alliance* had some additional story and character details in the manual, as well there was an in-game Email system that detailed the results of certain missions and other on-goings in the galaxy relative to the story that you may be able to read up on. But much of this game was cross-over with other events - for example the *Executor* raiding the smuggler asteroid detail was covered in *Shadows of the Empire*, and the Battle of Endor, of course, was covered in *Return of the Jedi*.

**Star Wars Galaxies**

Star Wars Galaxies had it's own story, **The Ruins of Dantooine**, published that details some of the events in the game. I got the impression this was supposed to be a longer series, but this is the only book I know of published around these particular events. Some books, like **Death Troopers**, had some carry over into the Star Wars Galaxies game, but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

**Shadows of the Empire**

This series has both a comic book series, and a novelization of the events that take place inside it. Unlike most of the other Star Wars games, this one has a firmer place in the Star Wars Expanded Universe, in that the events here are referenced frequently by other sources.

**Things to Avoid**

As I mentioned before, the *Knights of the Old Republic* comic series by Dark Horse has nothing to do with the game. The *Rogue Squadron comics and books* have very little to do with the games (though there are some occasional references and cross-overs). The controversial *Republic Commando* books have absolutely nothing to do with the game, though *Imperial Commando* deals with some of the events that take place after the game.

**Things Not To Worry About**

Obviously the *Star Wars Lego* games are spoofs, and should not be taken seriously. But the same should be said for the *Rebel Assault* and *Rebel Assault II* games. These games often take extreme liberty with the Star Wars universe (*Rebel Assault*, for example, has a rebel base on Tatooine) that cannot be rectified with the existing Expanded Universe canon.

The same can be true for most of the games that cover the same time period as the movies, for example the *Battlefront* Games often have different versions of key battles, like the Battle of Endor, where anyone can blow up the bunker.

*Star Wars Rebellion* can be written off for having absolutely no story worth speaking of. Some of the other strategy games have quite a bit of story (some of it very interesting) that is told only through the game, sadly.